# BindableEvent unbinding on character reset

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I have a BindableEvent that I need to use but when the character resets, the event cannot be used anymore. How can I make it qork even after reset? Here's my code:

```lua
local CS=game:GetService("ContextActionService")
local Player=game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
CS:BindAction("Chat Focus",function()
    spawn(function() ChatBar:CaptureFocus() end)
    ChatBar.PlaceholderText = ""
end,false,Enum.KeyCode.Slash)
Player.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid").Died:Connect(function()
    repeat wait(0.01) until Player.Character
    CS:BindAction("Chat Focus",function()
        spawn(function() ChatBar:CaptureFocus() end)
        ChatBar.PlaceholderText = ""
    end,false,Enum.KeyCode.Slash)
end)
```

Help would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your BindAction command into the StarterGUI folder, it will just work. You don't even need a Died event handler.